# Trying to transfer the output data from multiple python scripts to SQLite3

Tags: database, python-3.x, csv, sqlite, output

I'm running 12 different python scripts at the same time to screen for a given criteria out of thousands of data points each hour.

I would like to save the output data to a "master csv file" but figured it would be better to put the data into SQLite3 instead as I would be overwhelmed with csv files.

I am trying to transfer the output straight to SQLite3.

This is my script so far:

```
    symbol = []

    with open(r'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Results.csv') as f: 
        for line in f:
            symbol.append(line.strip())
    f.close

    path_out = (r'c:\\Users\\Desktop\\Results.csv')

    i=0
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [reformat your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the linked guide. Properly formatting your post increases the likelihood of you receiving a constructive response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you [can use a sqlite database concurrently](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), it might slow your processes down considerably.

Whenever a program wants to *write* to the database file, *the whole database has to be locked*:

> When SQLite tries to access a file that is locked by another process, the default behavior is to return SQLITE_BUSY.

So you could end up with more than one of your twelve processes waiting for the database to become available because one of them is writing.

Basically, concurrent read/write access is what client/server databases like PostgreSQL are made for. It is not a primary use case for sqlite.

So having the twelve programs each write a separate CSV file and merging them later is probably not such a bad choice, in my opinion. It is much easier than setting up a PostgreSQL server, at any rate.